# How to save an image from MDI Child

Tags: vb.net

I want to save an image from MDI Child but i get this error:
[image]

Here's the code

```
Private Sub mnuFileSep_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuFileSep.Click
    Dim saveFile As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog
    saveFile.Title = "Save Files"
    saveFile.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
    saveFile.Filter = "Jpg File|*.jpg"

    If saveFile.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        'An error appears from the line below
        Form2.PictureBox1.Image.Save(saveFile.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That error message suggests that Form2.PictureBox1.Image is Nothing.  Can you debug & break at that point and confirm whether it has been set correctly.

Comment: Be sure to learn how to use the debugger so you don't get that dialog and can inspect the variables in your program.  The basic diagnostic is that Form2.PictureBox1 does not have an image.  That's an easy mishap when you rely on the blasted default instance feature.  When you create the MDI child with New Form2 then Form2 in this code is not the same instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely source of the error is the use of `Form2`.  This attempts to access the "default instance" of Form2, while you have probably displayed a different instance with the "new" keyword.

One way to get a reference to the actual instance of Form2:

```
Private Sub mnuFileSep_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuFileSep.Click
    Dim f2 As Form2 = Me.MdiChildren.OfType(Of Form2).FirstOrDefault
    If Not IsNothing(f2) Then
        Dim saveFile As New SaveFileDialog
        saveFile.Title = "Save Files"
        saveFile.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        saveFile.Filter = "Jpg File|*.jpg"
        If saveFile.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            f2.PictureBox1.Image.Save(saveFile.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If you have more than one instance of Form2 open, then you could check to see if the active MdiChild is of type Form2, and use that instead:

```
Private Sub mnuFileSep_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuFileSep.Click
    If Not IsNothing(Me.ActiveMdiChild) AndAlso TypeOf(Me.ActiveMdiChild) Is Form2 Then
        Dim f2 As Form2 = DirectCast(Me.ActiveMdiChild, Form2)
        Dim saveFile As New SaveFileDialog
        saveFile.Title = "Save Files"
        saveFile.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        saveFile.Filter = "Jpg File|*.jpg"
        If saveFile.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            f2.PictureBox1.Image.Save(saveFile.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```